# How can I save a decent amount of information for a user without requiring registration?

Tags: html, cookies

Imagine a user is browsing store flyers on my website and they can press a button on a flyer item to add it to their "list" which will be on another page. I don't really want to require registration to use this list, so how could I store this information? The list could be pretty big, like imagine 200 items. Is it proper to store this information in cookies? I'd imagine cookies aren't meant for this much information? Perhaps there is a way to get a unique identifier for a user? Then I could store their list in my database and retrieve it through their unique identifier. Getting a unique identifier is easy on mobile but for web I imagine it would be a lot more trickier..

Comment: You're in luck, with HTML5, you can use localStorage.

Comment: How might a user delete local storage? I know clearing history deletes cookies. Is it the same for local storage?

Comment: You have functions that are essentially setter-getter methods. You can add elements/objects,etc to this.